# @OneToMany is giving null value in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
public class Enterprise{
.....
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Organization> organizations;
.....
}

public class Organization{
....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "enterprise_organization_map", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id") })
    private Enterprise enterprise;
....
}
```

When I tried to fetch Enterprise, I am not getting the mapped organizations. its returning null.

//print statement

Enterprise with Organizations:Enterprise [enterpriseId=13, enterpriseName=xyz, organizations=null]

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: how did you insert it , and how did you fetch it?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa

Using JpaRepository. Organization organization = new Organization(); organization.setOrganizationName("XYZSoftware"); organization.setEnterprise(enterprise); Organization savedOrganization = this.repository.save(organization); System.out.println("Enterprise with Organizations:" + savedOrganization.getEnterprise().getOrganizations()); System.out.println( "Enterprise with Organizations:" + this.enterpriseRepository.findOne(enterprise.getEnterpriseId‌​()));

Comment: Can you show the getter of `organizations`?

Comment: @LudovicGuillaume
getter is normal getter only. At the variable level I have mapped the organizations.
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Organization> organizations;

If I remove the organizations from the Enterprise.toString(), I am able to get it .
The issue now is, Enterprise->Organization->Enterprise->.... recursive object build is happening. I want to get the Object only once. How to fix it ?
i.e., only Enterprise->Organization.

Comment: We need more infos. On which context do you get a recursive issue ? Simple print, Json conversion, ...?

Comment: in simple print. And also for Json conversion also it will be recursive. If I add @JsonIgnore on Organization, it wil work for Enterprise. But If I tried to get the Organization, it wont give Organization.enterprise.
Can you please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Please update the question instead of dumping code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional one-to-many associations required helper methods to 'link' both entities, see the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application
>   developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times. The
>   addPhone() and removePhone() are utilities methods that synchronize
>   both ends whenever a child element is added or removed.

So you have to add to `Enterprise` at least one such method and use it when you add `Organization` to `Enterprise`:

```
public Enterprise addOrganization(Organization organization) {

    organization.setEnterprise(this);
    this.organizations.add(organization);
    return this;
}
```

I don't see such method in your code. I think this is the reason of your problem.

Additional useful info about one-to-many you can find here: [Best Practices for Many-To-One and One-To-Many Association Mappings](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/).

Comment: No. There is no issue with add or update. I have checked in DB as well. Anyway that issue fixed. 
Now the problem when I tried to fetch the records. 
At the variable level I have mapped the organizations. @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private List<Organization> organizations; If I remove the organizations from the Enterprise.toString(), I am able to get it . The issue now is, Enterprise->Organization->Enterprise->.... recursive object build is happening. I want to get the Object only once. How to fix it ? i.e., only Enterprise->Organization.

Comment: So this is another question? Could you post it as new one? And which approach helped you to solve your first question (about giving a null value)?

Comment: @Krishna 'Enterprise->Organization->Enterprise->' - it happens only in some method. You should to post the new question and specify full details.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the toString().