# SpringJPA - Saving child object in one-to-many relation does not show up in the parent object after its findOne()

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I save a child object and try to fetch the parent again, I do not get the associated child object. I am using SpringJPA and I have following One-to-many relation.

```
class ClassRoom {
     @Id
     private Integer classId;
     OneToMany(mappedBy="classRoom", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private Set<Student> students;

}
class Student {
     @Id
     private Integer studentId;
     @Column(name="class_room_id", insertable = false, updateable = false)
     private Integer classRoomId;
     ManyToOne
     JoinColumn(name = "class_room_id", referencedColumnName="class_room_id")
     private ClassRoom classRoom;
}
```

Even when I do ClassRoomRepository.findOne(classRoomId) it still returns just the one class. I believe its expected behavior as it returns the cached instance. Is there a way to force JPA to fetch all associations. I even tried to do the save and fetch in two separate transactions and I still get the same error.

Can someone guide me how to do this as I see this is a common use-case scenario ?

UPDATE:
Following is the code that invokes these transactions

```
class StudentProxy {
   public void saveAndLoadStudent() {
      studentService.saveStudent();
      studentService.loadClassRoom();
  }
}

class StudentService {
    @Transactional
    public void saveStudent() {
         studentRespository.save(student);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void loadClassRoom() {
          ClassRoom classRoom = classRoomRepository.findOne(classRoomId);
          // classRoom has no students in it.   
    }
```

Comment: If you save and fetch in two separate transactions, then there should be no problem. Otherwise, if the parent and its association have already been loaded, t's indeed the expected behavior. Without the code of your attempts, it's hard to say more. You can detech an entity and reload it if you want. Not sure why you would do that instead of just adding the child to its parent.

Comment: I have updated my question with the piece of code that does invokes the  two calls.

Comment: @DBS If what you want is fetching all the child entities eagerly you can use `JOIN FETCH`.

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45752395, maybe it will be helpful in your situation...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post how the `ClassRoom` should actually get a `Student`. But there is a common mistake that might be happening to you:

If you change the set of `Student`s in the `ClassRoom` this won't get saved because the relationship is controlled by the `Student` side.

Other than that JPA shouldn't use a cached instance if you start a new transaction, assuming you didn't configure a second level cache and even that should get invalidated.